# When to delete allocated memory in karatsuba's algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

Here's my implementation of karatsuba's algorithm,
It works well while the deletion part is commented but when I insert it to the code, it causes wrong ouput!
(for example for the test n=5, a=b={1, 2, 3, 4, 5})

```
void conv(int a[], int b[], int c[], int n)
{
    if (n == 1)
    {
        c[0] = a[0]*b[0];
        return;
    }
    int *C0 = new int[n];
    int *C1 = new int[n];
    int *C2 = new int[n];
    conv(a, b, C0, n/2);
    conv(a + n/2, b + n/2, C1, n/2);
    for (int i = 0; i < n/2; i++) 
        a[i] += a[i + n/2], b[i] += b[i + n/2];
    conv(a, b, C2, n/2);
    for (int i = 0; i < n/2; i++)
        a[i] -= a[i + n/2], b[i] -= b[i + n/2];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        c[i] += C0[i];
        c[i + n] += C1[i];
        c[i + n/2] += C2[i] - C1[i] - C0[i];
    }
/*  delete[] C0;
    delete[] C1;
    delete[] C2;*/
}
```

What is the problem with the deletion? Have I made the allocated memory free in a wrong way?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: There is une part suspicious in your code: you set a value in c vector at i+n. Which is the range of vectors a,b and c (I would guess n but is not stated).

Comment: a and b have size n but c has size 2n. (we pass the c with size n to the call with new n = n/2)

Comment: It looks like you're not fully initializing the C0 / C1 / C2 arrays before using them.

Comment: You didn't ask, but 'm telling you anyway: dynamically allocating and deleting your workspace like this makes Karatsuba slower than naive byte-by-byte multiplication. Instead, you should allocate three big arrays at the top level of recursion, and use dynamic pointers into these arrays. This has to be done with care.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of declaring them pointers you can declare them as vectors, then you need not worry about deletion. The problem here with deletion is in your code arguments you are actually sending c as a pointer so when you delete the pointers, you are still pointing to that address you have deleted not the value.

Answer (score 0):

In this loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        c[i] += C0[i];
        c[i + n] += C1[i];
        c[i + n/2] += C2[i] - C1[i] - C0[i];
    }
```

you are adding to elements of `c` which have never been initialized. (Presumably, you intended them to have been initialized to 0, no?)

I don't know what platform you are using, but let's assume that it is a platform on which a new memory allocation when no memory has ever been freed happens to be all zeros, but once a memory allocation is freed, it is possible to receive the freed allocation, which will have random values. In that case, removing the `delete` statements makes it more likely that all the memory allocations are fresh, while including them makes it highly likely that the memory blocks will be recycled.

In any event, using uninitialized values is undefined behaviour. You should probably explicitly set the newly allocated `C0`, `C1` and `C2` vectors to 0.

Comment: In each call of function, size of c is equal to 2*n. (when I pass n/2 to function, size of passed array is n). So c[0] ... c[2n-1] elements have been initialized before! Is it true?

Comment: Now I understand your meaning! You were right ;) This line solved the issue : fill(c, c + 2*n, 0);

Answer (score 0):

You can define IntArray class, and create it on the stack, instead of allocating memory directly. In this way, defined class manages allocated memory itself. (It frees its member int array 'data', when it goes out of scope.)

```
class IntArray{
public:
int* data;
int n;
IntArray(int n){
    this->n = n;
    data = new int[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        data[i] = 0;
    }
}
~IntArray(){
    if(data != NULL){
        delete[] data;
        data = NULL;
    }
}

};

void conv(int a[], int b[], IntArray &c, int n)
{
if (n == 1)
{
    c.data[0] = a[0]*b[0];
    return;
}
/*
int *C0 = new int[n];
int *C1 = new int[n];
int *C2 = new int[n];
*/
IntArray C0(n);
IntArray C1(n);
IntArray C2(n);

conv(a, b, C0, n/2);
conv(a + n/2, b + n/2, C1, n/2);
for (int i = 0; i < n/2; i++)
    a[i] += a[i + n/2], b[i] += b[i + n/2];
conv(a, b, C2, n/2);
for (int i = 0; i < n/2; i++)
    a[i] -= a[i + n/2], b[i] -= b[i + n/2];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    c.data[i] += C0.data[i];
    c.data[i + n] += C1.data[i];
    c.data[i + n/2] += C2.data[i] - C1.data[i] - C0.data[i];
}
}
```